# Class object value not displaying properly

Tags: django

I have implemented a counter in my Django program. It is not displaying as intended.

**From Views**

```
    class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        return data
```

I know this works because if I comment out the method

**From HTML Page**

```
    <small class="text-muted">{{ object.view_count }}</small>
```

How ever when I try to use the method it prints,

```
    F(view_count) + Value(1)
```

Instead of a number as intended.

I'm not sure what else to try as I am new to Django. I attempted to research how to fix it but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna give this a try:

```
self.object.view_count += 1
self.object.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply here increment the `view_count`, so `self.object.view_count += 1`. The above is a bit less save, since here, if the same `Post` is shown twice concurrently, it is, strictly speaking possible that one of the views will not be taken into account, probably `view_count` is however not that important:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.object.view_count += 1
        self.object.save()
        return data
```

If you really want to protect this against race conditions, you can save the `view_count`, and then make a save with `F('view_count') + 1`:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        vc = self.object.view_count
        self.object.view_count = F('view_count') + 1
        self.object.save()
        self.object.view_count = vc + 1
        return data
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much for your help.